# Separate configs, different indexes yet both logs go to both indexes

Tags: logstash

I have the following 2 config files:

> EMAIL READER

```
input {
  imap {
        host => "imap.gmail.com"
        user => "account@gmail.com"
        password => "pass"
        secure => true
        port => 993
        check_interval => 30

  }
}

output{
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "mailbox-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                user => user
                password => pass
        }
}
```

> FIREWALL-SYSLOG

```
input{

        syslog {
                type => "syslog"
                port => 55555
        }

}

output{
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "fortigate-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                user => user
                password => pass
        }
}
```

My problem is that for unknown reason both indexes get "mixed-up". Meaning logs from "mailbox" are stored in both the mailbox index AND the fortigate index, and logs from the "fortigate" index and stored in both the fortigate index AND the mailbox index.
I seem to have somehow created a duplicate index but I do not know how that is possible. I tried to re-create "mailbox" but same issue occures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone at Elastic forums helped me figure it out eventually. As it turns out Logstash requires conditioning in order to divert different data to different indexes. Here's a good example:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-with-output-elasticsearch-data-duplicate-on-index/101981/5

Comment: The underlying issue is that each event is run through your entire config.  If you have 10 filters and 3 outputs, each event will go through them all.   That's where the conditionals mentioned come into play.